# Proving statement about span and linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

**Theorem 1.7:** Let $S$ be a linearly independent subset of a vector space $V$,  and let $v \in V \setminus S$. Then $S \cup \{v\}$ is linearly dependent if and only if $v \in \text{span}(S)$.

**Statement:** If $S$ is a spanning set for a subspace $W$ and no proper subset of $S$ spans $W$, then $S$ is linearly independent.

*Proof 1.* Let $S_x$ be a proper subset of $S$. Suppose that $S_x$ does not span $W$. Choose some $w \in S \setminus S_x$.

Notice that $w$ satisfies $w \in W \setminus S_x$ and $w \not\in \text{span}(S_x)$ (if $w \in \text{span}(S_x)$, then $S$ is not linearly independent).

By Theorem 1.7, we know that $S_x \cup \{w\}$ is linearly independent.
If $S_x \cup \{w\} = S$, then we are done. Otherwise, repeat the argument with $S_x \cup \{w\}$ in place of $S_x$.

*Proof 2.* We prove the contrapositive. Suppose that $S$ is linearly dependent. Then there exists a set of distinct vectors $s_1, \ldots, s_n \in S$ and scalars $a_1, \ldots, a_n$, not all zero, such that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_is_i = 0$$
Without loss of generality suppose that $a_1$ is a nonzero scalar. Then
$$-a_1^{-1}\cdot\sum_{i=2}^n a_is_i = s_1$$
So, we may write $s_1$ as a linear combination of the vectors $s_2,\ldots, s_n$. Thus, $s_1 \in \text{span}(S \setminus s_1)$ and $\text{span}(S \setminus s_1) = \text{span}(S) = W$, and we see that a proper subset of $S$ spans $W$.

My questions:

1. Does the first proof work if the vector space is not finite dimensional? If not, how would I extend it?
2. Is the second proof correct?

Comment: your second proof is fine but the first proof is unclear. You want to prove $S$ is linearly independent but what if your initial choice $S_x$ was linearly dependent ?

Comment: Hm, maybe I can start with $S_x = \varnothing$ and then proceed with the same argument?

Comment: or maybe start with just one non-zero element set.